# type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<Object>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I'm using the image picker in flutter and trying to get the image. Before I select the image it appear like this:

**Before Upload Image**

[image]

**After Upload Image**

[image]

here is the code:

```
backgroundImage: _pickedImage != null
          ? Image.file(_pickedImage!) as ImageProvider
          : const AssetImage('assets/images/profile-icon.png'),
```

How should solve this error?

**Updated Error**

[image]

https://codeshare.io/oQpBvX

Comment: Change it to `FileImage(_pickedImage)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead, render your picked image with an image.file() widget then toggle the container with the image.file()

```
child: image == null
        ? Container(
            width: 400.w,
            height: 300.h,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: ExactAssetImage(imageUrl), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          )
        : Image.file(
            image!,
            width: 160.w,
            height: 160.h,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `FileImage` instead like so:

```
backgroundImage: _pickedImage != null
          ? FileImage(_pickedImage!)
          : const AssetImage('assets/images/profile-icon.png'),
```

Comment: It can't work too. I tried before. I updated the error on question.

Comment: Hey @kiku, it seems as if you have used `const` in your `DecorationImage` or `BoxDecoration` or `Container`...Please remove it, it should work.

Comment: Hey @Josteve, I sure that I not add any const there, i share the file in the link , u can help me take a look on there

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
backgroundImage: _pickedImage != null
          ? FileImage(_pickedImage!)
          : AssetImage('assets/images/profile-icon.png'),
```

Comment: It can't work too. I tried before. I updated the error on question.

Answer (score 0):

```
///I got the same issue while I am checking image is null or not I am using a container to show the image Hope this will help you,Thanks
    //////image inside a container 
        
         Container(
                                                height: 120,
                                                width: 120,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  image:DecorationImage(
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                      image: provider.currentLoggedInUser!.profilePicture!= null?
                                                      NetworkImage(provider.currentLoggedInUser!.profilePicture.toString())
                                                          :AssetImage('assets/managerPicture.jpeg') as ImageProvider),
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                      color: AppColors.white, width: 2.0),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
```

////you can also use the CachedNetworkImage plugin

[ChachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image/example)

```
     CachedNetworkImage(
          maxHeightDiskCache: 100,
         imageUrl: provider.currentLoggedInUser!.profilePicture.toString(),
 imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
       height: 120,
       width: 120,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
       shape: BoxShape.circle,
       image: DecorationImage(
       image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
       border: Border.all(
       color: AppColors.white, width: 2.0),
    
              ),
                 ),
     placeholder: (context, url) =>
    const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
     height: 120,
      width: 120,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      image:DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: AssetImage('assets/managerPicture.jpeg')),
      border: Border.all(
      color: AppColors.white, width: 2.0),
              ),
            ),
      fadeOutDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      fadeInDuration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
          ),
```

Comment: It can't work too, I wonder what is the `sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0" ` u guys using

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundImage: _pickedImage != null
      ? FileImage(_pickedImage!) 
      : const AssetImage('assets/images/profile-icon.png') as ImageProvider,
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?